# Is "adorable" used to describe an adult?

Tags: connotation

I've heard *adorable* sometimes used for kids. Is it ever used to describe an adult?

Comment: Brian Hyland (and others) seemed to think so: http://youtu.be/MjBOv-I5fmg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If the adult is [adorable](http://m.dictionary.com/d/?q=adorable&o=0&l=dir).

Comment: That this is the accepted answer suggest the question should be closed. This does not really answer the question, which is not "can it be used?", but whether or not it is (commonly, I venture).

Answer (score 8):

The word *adorable* as applied to an adult has to mean more than "good looking" or even "sexually attractive". For example, [Matt Bellassai describes the Australian diver Matthew Mitcham as "the most adorable Olympian ever"](http://www.buzzfeed.com/mattbellassai/matthew-mitcham-is-the-most-adorable-olympian-ever-6z51). If you read that article, it's quite clear that Matt finds Matthew attractive, but there's more to it than that. Matthew is "adorable" because he's cute, friendly, playful, and approachable. The word, as applied to adults, suggests a certain whimsy as well as good looks.

And the good looks of a Greek God or a model aren't really adorable either. It's the "cute" look you want, which is a bit harder to define. It's the sort of person who looks good with a good-natured grin, and who often has such a grin. (Perhaps I'm putting a little too much of my own taste into this bit.)

Answer (score 6):

*Adorable* can be used with adults, and domestic animals.

> My wife is so adorable.
>   I have four adorable Siamese cats.

Comment: Let's be clear: no man would say that about another man (may be exceptions.)

Comment: @Lambie I really doubt that.

Comment: Well, go out into the world and try it.

Answer (score 3):

I especially hear adorable applied to the elderly.  There is no reason it can't be applied to other adults as well.

Comment: The only reason not to might be that it always sounds a bit patronizing, at least to my British ears, when used to describe adults.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on context. As a rule adorable is used to describe babies, children, the elderly, and pets. It can have a minimalizing or patronizing connotation. Depending on its use it can also be condescending when applied to an adult. (i.e. It's just adorable the way she clips coupons to save a few pennies.)